# Sull'uso di "appassionato" e "affezionato"

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Ho cercato le parole "[affezionato](http://www.wordreference.com/definizione/affezionato)" e "[appassionato](http://www.wordreference.com/definizione/appassionato)" nei [dizionari](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/appassionato/).

**affezionato**

> Legato da affezione nei confronti di qcn. o di qcs.; attaccato, dedito.
>
> Esempi:
>
> Scolaro affezionato al maestro, agli studi.
>
> È affezionato al lavoro.

**appassionato**

Participio passato dei verbi:

- **appassionare:**

> Attrarre fortemente, interessare vivamente; avvincere. Destare in qcn. una passione, un grande interesse per qcs.

- **appassionarsi:**

> Prendere passione, provare grande interesse per qcs.

> Esempi:
>
> Gli studenti si sono appassionati alla lettura dei classici.
>
> Gli appassionati della musica lirica.
>
> Un appassionato della montagna.

Dunque, si può essere affezionati agli studi o al lavoro e si è appassionati alla lettura, alla musica, ecc. Mi chiedo se è possibile interscambiare questi termini (con sfumature di significato diverse) in frasi di questo tipo. Ad esempio:

- Era molto *appassionata* della montagna.
- Era molto *affezionata* alla montagna.

- Mio fratello era un *appassionato* di partite di calcio.
- Mio fratello era *affezionato* alle partite di calcio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intanto, l'affetto e la passione sono – quanto meno – due gradazioni molto diverse. La seconda denota un amore, un trasporto molto maggiore, quasi esclusivo, mentre l'affetto si può provare per parenti, amici, gatti, una vecchia borsa, una strada abituale. Uno può essere affezionato agli amici o ai colleghi, ma si mostrerà appassionato nei confronti della persona amata.

Non è un caso che negli esempi che hai trovato si sia affezionati ad aspetti della vita pressoché obbligatori (studi e lavoro) ma appassionati, paradossalmente, agli aspetti più voluttuari (musica e altri piaceri della vita).

Certo, uno può essere “appassionato” al lavoro (più probabilmente uno scienziato che studia qualcosa di molto promettente che non un impiegato delle poste), ma se ti esprimi così stai usando il termine in un senso più pregnante. Viceversa, se uno fosse solo “affezionato” a un'attività a cui dedica il poco tempo libero che ha (e magari si alza presto, e magari ci spende un bel po' per praticarla), be', forse è meglio se cambia hobby.

Comment: Dunque, se ho capito bene, essere affezionati alla montagna o alle partite di calcio suona piuttosto strano. È così?

Comment: @Charo: Sì, suonerebbe curioso, o marcato, come a voler sottolineare che è un'attività che si fa senza troppa convinzione, per abitudine, perché ci si va fin da bambini etc.

Answer (score 3):

Pensa all'etimologia: *appassionato* viene dal latino *passio* che a sua volta è legato a verbo *patior* (patire, soffrire). L'aspetto di sofferenza non è necessariamente implicito, ma certamente *patior* indica un sentimento molto intenso.

La forma *appassionare* (*ad*+*patior*) è più blanda perché contiene l'idea di un andare verso la passione vera e propria.

Il termine *passione* ha, al giorno d'oggi, solo il significato “sentimentale”, direi di un sentimento che si esprime con tutto di sé stessi. Sopravvive nelle locuzioni cristallizzate riguardanti la *passione di Cristo*. Il *paziente* che si reca dal medico ha la stessa etimologia, il termine ha ovviamente il senso di patimento fisico piuttosto che spirituale.

*Affetto*, viceversa viene da *adficio* (fare qualcosa a qualcuno, influenzare il corpo o la mente per portarli in un certo stato, secondo il [dizionario Lewis-Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=afficio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)) e denota qualcosa di molto meno intenso della passione, almeno esteriormente: la passione può essere simulata o artificiosa, l'affetto no.