# Quale preposizione usare dopo "appassionato"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Cercando casi di uso di "appassionato" per porre [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3575/707), ho scoperto che si possono scrivere diverse preposizioni dopo tale aggettivo. Ecco alcuni esempi:

- Gli studenti si sono appassionati *alla* lettura dei classici.
- È un appassionato *della* montagna.
- È molto appassionato *per* la caccia.

Non riesco a capire quale preposizione si debba usare in queste espressioni. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La preposizione più comune sembra essere **di** come suggerito dal Diz. Garzanti è come risulta da Ngram. Altre preposizioni vengono  usate e sono, a mio avviso, accettabili.

[Appassionato](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=appassionato): ( Diz. Garzanti)

> - che, chi coltiva un interesse particolare per qualcosa **[+ di]**: mio padre era un lettore appassionato **di gialli**; sei un appassionato **della fotografia**?

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appassionato%20a%2Cappassionato%20di%2Cappassionato%20per&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cappassionato%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cappassionato%20di%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bappassionato%20di%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAppassionato%20di%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cappassionato%20per%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bappassionato%20per%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAppassionato%20per%3B%2Cc0) appassionato di/per/a.

Comment: Notazione da madrelingua: a me "appassionato *della* fotografia" suona male, forse solo perché non è molto comune.

Comment: @martina: È più comune "appassionato di fotografia"?

Comment: @Charo Si, senza dubbio. Anzi, "appassionato *della* x", dove x è una disciplina, un interesse, una cosa che si fa per piacere, io non l'ho mai sentito!

Comment: Grazie, @martina. Questi commenti hanno motivato un'altra mia [domanda](http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3580/7).