# Sull'uso dell'articolo determinativo dopo "appassionato" + "di"

Tags: word-usage, articles

Ancora un'altra domanda sull'uso dell'aggettivo "appassionato" + la preposizione "di". [Questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3575/707) e anche [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/3579/707) a [quest'altra domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/3578/707) riportano esempi di uso della costruzione "appassionato" + "di" + articolo determinativo:

> - Gli appassionati della musica lirica.
> - Un appassionato della montagna.
> - Un appassionato della fotografia.

Tutti questi esempi sono tratti da dizionari. Alcuni commenti in questi post, però, sembrano suggerire che questa costruzione sia caduta piuttosto in disuso e che sia molto più comune l'uso di "appassionato" + "di" senza articolo determinativo. Ad esempio:

- Gli appassionati di musica lirica.
- Un appassionato di fotografia.

È così?

Answer (score 2):

Dal punto di vista dell'analisi grammaticale, la costruzione varia solamente nel senso che o viene usata la preposizione semplice *"di"*, oppure si ricorre all'utilizzo delle preposizioni articolate: *della*, *delle*, *dei*, ...

Personalmente, sono più abituato all'uso della preposizione semplice. Il fatto che essa prevalga sulla preposizione articolata potrebbe avere sia motivazioni *eufoniche* - per chi è abituato, suona meglio "di" piuttosto che "della" - sia di *semplificazione* della lingua.

Answer (score -2):

Gli appassionati *della* musica lirica sono quelli che si limitano ad ascoltarla, magari andando qualche sera a teatro, mentre quelli *di* musica lirica la studiano e la praticano.

Un appassionato *della* montagna è colui che usa andarci qualche fine settimana durante l'anno o che non resiste ad adandarci se ha opportunità di farlo, mentre l'appassionato *di* montagna ci va sempre, ci permane lunghi periodi o ci vive anche se potrebbe vivere altrove.

Un appassionato *della* fotografia è colui a cui piace studiare fotografia in senso generale, e magari fare qualche scatto di tanto in tanto, mentre l'appassionato *di* fotografia è colui che darebbe chissà cosa per farsi un safari fotografico.

Spero di aver chiarito a sufficienza la differenza; differenza che consiste nel fatto che il *di* esprime un grado di coinvolgimento molto maggiore di *della*.

Comment: Questa è un'opinione, non un fatto, e non ha riscontro da alcuna parte.